# Какой хук срабатывает при выводе записей в post_type

Tags: wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Зарегистрировал post_type с полями custom-fields, добавил новую запись c полями Имя и Дата, нужно что бы в дальнейшем они выводились в такой последовательности (по id записи) при редактирование а они выводятся по алфавиту.
Хук pre_get_posts не срабатывает.
Поля (имя, дата) создаются автоматически.

```html
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_types' );

function register_post_types() {
  register_post_type( 'barthday', [
        'labels' => [
            'name'               => 'Barthday',
            'singular_name'      => 'Barthday',
            'add_new'            => 'Добавить дату',
            'add_new_item'       => 'Добавление даты',
            'edit_item'          => 'Редактировать дату',
            'new_item'           => 'Новая дата',
            'view_item'          => 'Смотреть дату',
            'search_items'       => 'Искать  дату',
            'not_found'          => 'Не найдено',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'Не найдено в корзине',
            'menu_name'          => 'Barthday',
        ],
        'public'              => false,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'custom-fields' )
    ] );
}

add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'set_default_fields' );

function set_default_fields( $post_ID ) {
  if( !chek_id_post_to_post_type_barthday( $post_ID ) ) return;

  foreach( [ 'Имя', 'Дата' ] as $field ) {
    $current_field_value = get_post_meta( $post_ID, $field, true );

    $default_value = '';

    if ( $current_field_value == '' && !wp_is_post_revision( $post_ID ) ) {
      add_post_meta( $post_ID, $field, $default_value, true );
    }
  }

  return $post_ID;
}

function chek_id_post_to_post_type_barthday( $id ) {
  $get_screen = get_current_screen();

  return ( $get_screen->id === 'barthday' ) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Напиши свой код

Comment: @SeVlad, добавил.

Comment: Ну а дальше? Как и где выводишь?

Comment: @SeVlad, нужно что бы в админ панели отображалось. Добавил скрин.

Comment: 1. `pre_get_posts` для фронта, а не для админки. 2. Включи отображение ПП справа вверху в настройках экрана.

Comment: @SeVlad, мне нужно что бы поле "Имя" ( ID = n ) при редактирование в админки было выше поля "Дата" ( ID = n + 1 )

Comment: Наконец-то стало понятно чего ты хочешь. И дам тебе совет - используй плагины для работы с ПП. С ними не только порядок можно отрегулировать, но и правильные типы полей задать и исключить возможность  ошибок в именовании ключей (у тебя сейчас очень неудобно и даже опасно сделано)